# Why isn't parent().remove() working here?

Tags: html, jquery, youtube, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I currently am trying to make the new YouTube layout more useable for me. To be exact, I want to remove some of the buttons on the video page, such as the "Thanks" button using Tampermonkey.

Since most of these buttons have generic class names, I thought of finding the correct HTML object using the SVG icon used for the button. As far as I can tell, the SVGs get loaded via a `<path>` object, where the attribute `d` is used as some kind of identification for the correct symbol. The object for the "Share" button for example looks like this: `<path d="M15-verylongstring" class="style-scope yt-icon"></path>`

I know, its not a good or future-proof solution, but I have no idea how else I could do this, so whatever.

The problem however is, that I can't remove this object. Or to be exact, I can't remove it's parent. I search for the button and try to remove it using the following Tampermonkey script:

```
const x = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {//
  let d = x[i].attributes.d.nodeValue;
  if (d == "M15-verylongstring"){ //share button svg
      //x[i].remove(); //case1
      //x[i].parent().remove(); //case2
  };
}
```

The two commented cases are where the problem is. In case 1, this code removes the HTML object `<path>` and nothing else. So if you load any YouTube video with this code running, you see the "Share" button, but instead of the icon you see an empty space.

In case 2, it should (as I see it) remove the parent of this `<path>` object, which is a `<g>` object. But as soon as I run it, nothing changes compared to the base YouTube page with no extra code. The icon is there and even with Inspect, i can't really see if the code even does something.

Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

**You can not change an `<iframe>` element by javascript/jquery when your page URL and iframe URL isn't the same.**

*[Since I don't have 50 reputations to comment, I answered here. Sorry for that]*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Could you further explain what you mean with that? I don't really see an `<iframe>` html element there (and as far as I understand iframes, this doesn't really seem to fit here? isnt it all youtube?)